# How to implement the cropping feature similar to Android Phone (default) in iOS.?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6.1

I have used BJImageCropper Class from Github to implement the functionality for cropping but I want the Image Cropping like Android Default Crop Box.

Like this:

[image: Cropping in Android]

Comment: There's no such thing as default Android Crop Box. Which application are you using ?

Comment: I have edited the Photo.
I want the Cropping with the Arrows as the sides or edges whichever is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't found something with arrows .. but you can check this:

- [Image Cropper](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/image-cropper)
- [JBCroppableView](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/jbcroppableview)

As mentioned by CRDave in comments, you can check this link
also https://github.com/nicholjs/BFCropInterface

Comment: Thanks..This will help me a lot

Comment: @CRDave Thanks for that link. I have added that in answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

If u want cropper like in fb app, try to use mine.
https://github.com/quaddef/QDImageCropper